# Is it possible to set empty string as a class selector in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I have a variable which have empty string as default value and it can be changed dynamically based on skin name. So I tried to write my sass selector like this.

**default.scss:**

```
$skin: '';
```

**green.scss:**

```
$skin: 'green';
```

**main.scss:**

```
@import 'default.scss';
.#{$skin} .header{
    color: black;
}
```

So I expected the below output from generated CSS.

```
.header{
  color: black;
}
```

and

```
.green .header{
   color: black;
}
```

But it throws below error while compiling 
**Invalid CSS after ".": expected class name, was ".header"**

Comment: when `$skin` is empty your output is `.  .header` so you could move the dot inside the variable

Comment: @fcalderan: Thanks for the update. Is it possible to do this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function for this:

```
$skin: 'green';
@function skin(){ 
    @if $skin != '' { @return '.' + $skin + ' '; } 
    @else { @return ''; }
}
```

Now you could use it like this:

```
#{skin()} .header { ... }
```

Which will output:

```
.green .header { display: block; }
```

It might be better to use a better global variable name (skin seems like something that might quickly be reused - I would suggest something like `$global-skin-name` or something, but thats just semantics).